# Как увеличить последний  элемент  в этой переменной  на +1 ?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$p = "vopros1";
?>
```

Comment: $p = "vopros9";

Что должно быть дальше?

    $p = "vopros0";

Тогда что после него?

    $p = "vopros1";

Или все-таки после $p = "vopros9":

    $p = "vopros10";

Тогда может быть стоит задать вопрос следующим образом:

>> Каким образом сделать переменную-счетчик, в которой первая часть - строка, а вторая инкрементируется?

Тогда ответ будет примерно таким:

    $constPart = 'vopros';

    $numPart = 1;
    $p = $constPart + $numPart; //$p = 'vopros1';
    ....
    $numPart++;
    $p = $constPart + $numPart; //$p = 'vopros2';
    ....

Comment: Или "vopros1" вы получаете откуда-то? И вам нужно увеличить не последний знак (читай цифру), а последнее число?

В общем - можно ли поподробнее описать задачу, чтобы можно было дать более-менее адекватный ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$p = "vopros1";
echo substr_replace($p,substr($p,-1) + 1, -1); // vopros2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
const WHILE_COUNT = 10;
$count = NULL;

$p = 'vopros';

while ($count<=WHILE_COUNT)
{
++$count;   
printf ("%s%s <br>\n",$p,$count); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$p = "vopros1";
$p = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($m) { return ++$m[0]; }, $p);
```

PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 0):

<?php
const WHILE_COUNT = 10;
$count = NULL;

$p = 'vopros';

while ($count<=WHILE_COUNT)
{
++$count;
$p = 'vopros'.$count; 
echo $p;
}
?>

Помоему так намного проще ... :)
Или ты хочеш увеличивать переменную при редиректе страницы, тогда надо или куки или сесию....